# Неявное поведение поля NSManagedObject'а

Tags: objective-c, ios, coredata

Имею некий `NSManagedObject`-обьект названный, скажем `Object`. У него есть поле `info` типа `NSString`. По логике программы я должен иметь возможность сохранить в это поле пустое значение, то есть строку нулевой длины. При сохранении я так и поступаю. Но когда я фетчу данный обьект из `Core Dat`'ы и логирую значение этого поля оно уже равно `(null)`. Если была сохранена строка ненулевой длины то она отдается корректно. Если это ошибка то не понимаю на каком этапе я могу ее допустить. В целях теста присваиваю значение полю, делаю `save` контексту и сразу тут же его фетчу. Получаю такой результат. Чем может быть обусловлено такое поведение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ах, как я люблю вопросы, в которых (<strike>без бутылки</strike>) без **research effort'а** сразу и не разобраться.

Если серьёзно, то мои тесты не подтверждают то, что вы говорите: ниже я привожу два тестовых сценария (у меня они оба выполняются).

User - это просто тестовая entity, которая имеет поле `name` типа `string` с включенной (это дефолт у Xcode) опцией `"optional"` (то есть оно необязательное, то есть может быть `nil`'ом), я полагаю, что у вас на вашем текстовом поле `optional` тоже включено.

Так вот первый сценарий - это мы приравниваем `name` тестового пользователя к пустой строке **@""**, сохраняем контекст и фетчим его заново. И убеждаемся, что поле таки является пустой строкой.

Второй сценарий - это мы заведомо приравниваем `name` к `nil` и закономерно убеждаемся после фетча, что name - это `nil`.

Вывод из всего этого такой: похоже вы сохраняете не строку, а nil.

Некоторое время назад я создал на Github [специальный репозиторий](https://github.com/stanislaw/CocoaSpecs) для того, чтобы изучать разные тонкости устройства Cocoa. Для этого я просто прописываю подробные тесты для соответствующих аспектов поведения Core Data или NS-объектов, которые хочу изучить. Ваш случай я только что расположил [здесь см. CoreData_Integration](https://github.com/stanislaw/CocoaSpecs/tree/master/CocoaSpecs/CoreData). Если будет желание освоить такой Test-Driven способ изучения тонкостей Cocoa, можно постучаться ко мне в скайп, и я объясню, как это работает, так как инструкции по эксплуатации проекта пока что нет.

```
describe(@"Behavior of string-NSString fields", ^{
    context(@"When a string field is set to empty string", ^{
        it(@"should return its value as an empty string (not nil!)", ^{
            User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([User class]) inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext()];

            user.name = @"";

            [managedObjectContext() save:nil];

            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"User"];

            NSError *error;
            NSArray *fetchResult = [managedObjectContext() executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
            }

            user = (User *)[fetchResult lastObject];

            [[user.name should] equal:@""];
        });
    });

    context(@"When a string field is set to nil", ^{
        it(@"should return its value as nil", ^{
            User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([User class]) inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext()];

            user.name = nil;

            [managedObjectContext() save:nil];

            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"User"];

            NSError *error;
            NSArray *fetchResult = [managedObjectContext() executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
            }

            user = (User *)[fetchResult lastObject];

            [[user.name should] beNil];
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: да, простые тесты решают... нужно заняться вопросом почему я получаю такой результат

Comment: Было бы интересно узнать, в чем было дело в результате.